# Adding an Event via jQuery to newly created DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am trying to assign an event to a newly created DOM Element:

```
var Element = document.createElement("div");
$(document).on('click',Element,function() {
    console.log("B");
});
```

After executing this code and clicking on the newly created div, nothing happens.
Any idea why?

I have also tried:

```
var Element = document.createElement("div");
$(Element).click(function(event) {
    console.log("B");
});
```

Comment: a) `.on` doesn't accept a DOM element as the second argument (it, accepts a selector, http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler). b) you also have to add the element to the document. The second one should work then. However, you should also add some content to the element, otherwise it won't have any dimensions and you can't target it with the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

#### You need to add the element to the DOM before it will receive events.

Here's one way to do it:

```
var $div = $('<div>')
  .text('Click Me!')
  .on('click', function() {
    alert('Clicked!');
  });

$(document.body).append($div);

// Now you can click on it and see the alert.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery...

```
var Element = $("<div/>").click(function() {console.log("B");}).appendTo('body');
```

Of course, append it where you need it...

Answer (score 0):

Just bind your event on the body and pass your selector in parameter like this:

```
$('body').on('click','.foo',function() {
    console.log("B");
});

var Element = document.createElement("div").className = "foo";
```

Here the codepen :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xvLqo